# WebAPI route to root URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI application that is used for some RESTful operations in the database. It works great, but I want to match a route with the root URL. For example, I want to go to the root of the site and see some useful information that are dynamically generated.

Currently, I have it setup so that it follows the standard convention of `api/{controller}/{action}`, but how can I show this information when navigated to the root instead of something like `api/diagnostics/all`?

Basically what I want is, when the user navigates to the root URL, I want to route that request to `TestController.Index()`

I have the following setup in the WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Index",
        routeTemplate: "",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, controller = "Test" }
    );
}
```

And this is what my TestController.cs looks like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    [Route("TestService"), HttpGet]
    public string Index()
    {
         return "Service is running normally...";
    }        
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear please elaborate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically what I want is, when the user navigates to the root URL, I
>   want to route that request to TestController.Index()

In this case make sure that you have not decorated your TestController.Index action with this attribute:

```
[Route("TestService")]
```

So here's how your TestController might look like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Service is running normally...";
    }
}
```

And now simply navigate to `/` or `/api`.

Comment: Thanks Darin. My life is complete now.

Answer (score 12):

You could also simply use (`[Route("")]`):

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    [Route(""), HttpGet]
    public string Index()
    {
         return "Service is running normally...";
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a route for the default URL in WebApiConfig.cs. Here's an example where the root URL is mapped to method `HomeController.Index()`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Root",
    routeTemplate: "",   // indicates the root URL
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }   // the controller action to handle this URL
);
```

Comment: Thanks mate.. Worked like a charm!